# Polar Plot with no R value

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The question asked to do a polar plot of $\theta = \pi/7$ so it is not in the usual form of $r=$ and only has a $\theta$ value.

I think this would be a line, but it's difficult to see this.  Would this result in a line?

Comment: It would result in a line. Think of it as all the possible pair values $(r, \theta)$ with $\theta = \frac{\pi}{7}$

Comment: Possibly a *ray* (half a line)

Comment: Ah, I see this now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would.  Think of the analogous sort of thing in Cartesian coordinates -- it would not have bothered you to plot $x=5$, even though no $y$ appears.

One subtlety arises: Is it a line or a ray extending from the origin?  If you allow negative values of $r$ being equivalent to the corresponding absolute value of $r$ with $\theta$ increased by $180^\circ$ then it is a line; if not, then it is a ray.